# SQL Query for YTD & MTD

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find YTD and MTD totals for total sales. The total sales is derived by multiplying "Order Quantity" and "Unit price" and subtracting "Discount_Applied".

Here is my query,

```
select orderdate,datename(month,orderdate) as Mnth,year(orderdate) as YR, sum((unit_price*order_quantity)-discount_applied) as Total_Sales,
sum((unit_price*order_quantity)-discount_applied) over (partition by year(orderdate) order by orderdate) as YTD,
sum((unit_price*order_quantity)-discount_applied) over (partition by year(orderdate),datename(month,orderdate) order by orderdate) as MTD
from sales
group by orderdate,datename(month,orderdate),year(orderdate)
```

However, when I run this query, it gives me an error saying

> Column 'sales.Unit_Price' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

I guess it has something to do with the windows function I am using, but can't figure out specifically the problem. Can someone help.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help immensely. Do you want your main data grouped by each day, or do you only want to see the YTD and MTD figures?

Answer (score 1):

When you use a window function, it is calculated after any possible `GROUP BY` aggregation. So those columns don't exist anymore, only the aggregation exists.

Instead, you need to `SUM` the `SUM`: you need to do a windowed sum over the aggregate sum.

```sql
SELECT
  s.orderdate,
  DATENAME(month, s.orderdate) as Mnth,
  YEAR(s.orderdate) as YR,
  SUM((s.unit_price * s.order_quantity) - s.discount_applied) as Total_Sales,
  SUM(SUM((s.unit_price * s.order_quantity) - s.discount_applied) OVER
      (PARTITION BY YEAR(s.orderdate) ORDER BY EOMONTH(s.orderdate), s.orderdate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as YTD,
  SUM(SUM((s.unit_price * s.order_quantity) - s.discount_applied)) OVER
      (PARTITION BY YEAR(s.orderdate), EOMONTH(s.orderdate) ORDER BY s.orderdate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as MTD
FROM sales s
GROUP BY
  s.orderdate;
```

Note also that `EOMONTH` is a little more efficient than `DATENAME`, and that adding the month to the `YTD` ordering means it can use the same sort, without affecting the calculation.

Also `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` is a little more efficient than the default  `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`.